# CodedUI Test: Keyboard.SendKeys List of Keys

Tags: coded-ui-tests

I am trying to find list of all keyboard key for send into this method.

For example. If I need send Backspace button. What string I must sent into method: "{Backspace}" ?

Comment: It is there in MSDN itself. Check [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx).